# Terminator dock icon - no middle click new window

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, launcher, icons, terminator

A bit of an odd one. I have installed terminator, and added a keyboard shortcut (via unity configuration manager) so that terminator is launched via the shortcut win-i.

Now, if I have launched terminator via the launcher, then pressing win-i will open a terminator window, but there will be a separate app icon in the dock. alt-` will not cycle between the windows, which makes it seem like they are separate instances.

[image: dock with two terminator icons]

Now, middle clicking on the terminator icon that was launched via the launcher opens a new terminator window. Middle clicking the other terminator icon does nothing. pressing win-i creates a new terminal window that is grouped with the other terminator windows launched via the keyboard shortcut.

any ideas on how to fix this so that terminator windows launched via the keyboard shortcut will allow new windows with middle click?

Answer (score 0):

ok, after a restart (not the first one since configuring shortcuts etc) it now seems to behave as expected. Still seems like a bit of a bug, but has resolved itself for now.